# Twoside Header Formating

Tags: header-footer, double-sided

When switching to double side format (using the university document class)

```
\documentclass[12pt,phd,a4paper,twoside]{ucl_thesis}
```

the header on all the even pages switches from Section to the Chapter, how can I make it that all pages have the section as the header. I'm not sure, but I understand why latex suddenly does this in the two side format?

Thanks.

Comment: You can customize headers and footers using `fancyhdr`.

Answer (score 1):

Put this before `\begin{document}`

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textsl{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[C]{\nouppercase{\textsl\rightmark}}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt,phd,a4paper,twoside]{ucl_thesis}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textsl{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[C]{\nouppercase{\textsl\rightmark}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{My first chapter}
\section{My first section}
\lipsum
\section{My second section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]